# An error occurred (MissingAuthenticationTokenException) when calling the UpdateFunctionCode operation Lambda AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a function in my Lambda named `my-s3-function`. I need to add [this](https://github.com/ZJONSSON/node-unzipper) dependency to my Lambda Node.JS. I have followed [this part](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-package.html#nodejs-package-dependencies) to update the script with dependency included (though, I didn't follow the step wherein I need to zip the folder using `zip -r function.zip .` but instead I zip the folder by right-clicking it on my PC).

The zip file's structured like this inside:

```
|node_modules
    |<folders>
    |<folders>
    |<folders>
    ... // the list goes on
|index.js
|package_lock.json
```

Upon typing the code `aws lambda update-function-code --function-name my-s3-function --zip-file fileb://function.zip` to the terminal, I get the following response:

`An error occurred (MissingAuthenticationTokenException) when calling the UpdateFunctionCode operation: Missing Authentication Token`

What should I do to resolve this?

Comment: from the error, you shared < MissingAuthenticationTokenException>  it seems like an authentication error.  You can use [sts get-caller-identity](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sts/get-caller-identity.html) to check if the credentials are correct.

Comment: @samtoddler I am getting `An error occurred (MissingAuthenticationToken) when calling the GetCallerIdentity operation: Request is missing Authentication Token` error when I try the code `aws sts get-caller-identity`

Comment: your credentials are not correct in that case verify your credentials which you have on your machine and you think they should be via the console. Double check `~/.aws/credentials` file and your environment variables for the credentials. Environment credentials takes precedence over `~/.aws/credentials`

Comment: after I change the credentials into [this](https://i.imgur.com/7y2yeXh.png) , I am now getting [this alternate error](https://i.imgur.com/kkQfRuV.png) . This is the output whenever I type the [`~/.aws/config` command](https://i.imgur.com/zb8yPa3.png)

Comment: Try first with exporting the credentials as described [Environment variables to configure the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html). Once you are sure your credentials are correct then you can follow this [Configuration and credential file settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html)

Comment: after following your procedure step by step, I now succeeded in uploading my package. thank you! [here is the successful screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/GmBkKet.png)

(I would delete this part of the comment to remind me to upvote your comment since I've reach the daily upvote limit)

Comment: I added the explanation as to the answer. It will help whoever stumbles upon this in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments , this got resolved by configuring the credentials as described in the documentation.

> Try first with exporting the credentials as described [Environment variables to configure the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html). Once you are sure your credentials are correct then you can follow this [Configuration and credential file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html)